# Json rpc claculator

Tags: json, rpc

My main activity: I have created threads and handler and tried calling it to establish a connection to a particular server:

```
    public void mResult (){
        Double secondNum = Double.parseDouble(screenView.getText().toString());

        Double result = 0.0;
        this.result=result;
// thread call

            android.os.Handler aHandler = new android.os.Handler();
            DoCalc myCalc = new DoCalc(aHandler, firstNum, secondNum, Operation);
            myCalc.start();


        screenView.setText(String.valueOf(result));
    }
```

my main thread

```
    class DoCalc extends Thread {

        private android.os.Handler handler;

        private double left,right;
        private String oper;


        public DoCalc(android.os.Handler myHandle, double left, double right, String oper){
            this.handler = myHandle;
            this.left = left;
            this.right = right;
            this.oper = oper;
        }

        public DoCalc(Handler aHandler, Double firstNum, Double secondNum, String operation){


            this.handler = aHandler;
            this.left = firstNum;
            this.right = secondNum;
            this.oper = operation;
        }


        public void run(){
            Double result = 0.0;
            String url = "http://129.219.151.99:8080/JsonRPC/calc";
            try{
                HttpJsonRpcClientTransport transport =
                        new HttpJsonRpcClientTransport(new URL(url));
                transport.call(url);
                              LoggingPermission JsonRpcInvoker;
                org.json.rpc.client.JsonRpcInvoker invoker = new JsonRpcInvoker();
                Calculator calc = invoker.get(transport, "calc", Calculator.class);
                if(oper.equals("+")){
                    result = calc.add(left,right);

                }

                if(oper.equals("-")){
                    result = calc.subtract(left, right);
                }
                if(oper.equals("*")){
                    result = calc.multiply(left, right);
                }
                if(oper.equals("/")){
                    result = calc.divide(left, right);
                }
              //FinalResult set = new FinalResult(result);
                handler.post(new FinalResult(result));
               // set.start();
            }catch (Exception ex){
                android.util.Log.w("calc","exception in call: "+ex.getMessage());
            }
        }



  class FinalResult extends Thread implements Runnable  {
                double result;
               EditText screenView;
                public FinalResult(double result){
                    this.result = result;
                }
                public void run(){
            android.util.Log.w("calc","result is: "+result);
            System.out.println("result is"+result);
            screenView.setText(String.valueOf(result));
        }
    }

}
}
```

I think my json rpc is not working am just getting 0.0 when ever I do any calculation